# Unexpected CUDA errors on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python, theano, pythonanywhere

```
2020-04-24 00:19:23.554136: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'libcuda.so.1'; dlerror
: libcuda.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2020-04-24 00:19:23.554173: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-04-24 00:19:23.554190: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (b
lue-liveconsole8): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
2020-04-24 00:19:23.554604: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was no
t compiled to use: AVX2 AVX512F FMA
2020-04-24 00:19:23.562445: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:102] CPU Frequency: 2300045000 Hz
2020-04-24 00:19:23.562633: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x5c99210 initialized for platform Host (this does not g
uarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-04-24 00:19:23.562655: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-04-24 00:19:23.630585: F tensorflow/core/platform/env.cc:351] Check failed: -1 != path_length (-1 vs. -1)
```

I do not understand why I receive these errors when using a Theano backend on PythonAnywhere. I saved my model using a CPU on Google Colab and am trying to load it on PythonAnywhere but I get these errors. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: It appears that you are still loading tensorflow, and not theano. Have a look at https://keras.io/backend/ for how to configure your backend to be theano.

Comment: @Glenn I changed the backend to Theano in the .json file and when I initially run this program, I get the message "Using Theano backend". Do you think that I did not do it properly because TensorFlow shows up in the errors?

Comment: Ok. This is strange. I just created a model and then loaded it into a web app and it ran fine. What version of keras are you using and what version of Python are you using?

Comment: @Glenn Yes, it has to do with the version; I was able to fix this error by switching to Python 3.7 from Python 3.8. Everything works smoothly now. Thank you.